# display a div above another - css

Tags: css

I have a page with 7 divs as below;

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="head"></div>
    <div id="A">
        <div id="A1">A1</div>
        <div id="A2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="B"></div>
    <div id="foot"></div>
</div>
```

The styling is like below;

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#A, #B, #foot {
    position: absolute;
}
#head{
    background: #FF9900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
}
#A {
    top: 35px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 35px;
    background-color: #999999;
}
#A1{
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: #CC0066;
}
#B {
    top: 35px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 35px;
    background-color: #99CC00;
}
#foot{
    background: #0066CC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But my div `A1` is not getting displayed. A working fiddle is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/rGGEK/25/). I want to display div `A1` above div `B`. How can I fix this??

Thanks in advance... `:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: your working fiddle is indeed working. I mean, check this fiddle: I see the A1: http://jsfiddle.net/rGGEK/13/

Comment: Shows up fine in the fiddle you posted. But hides itself once the CSS here is put in the fiddle

Comment: @Above; the fiddle is editted, the above code is the original code. :-)

Comment: I want to display div `A1` above div `B`.. My question and fiddle updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #A1 div is being covered by you #B div. Add z-index:100; (or some other z-index number) to your #A div CSS. See example here http://jsfiddle.net/rGGEK/22/ .

Comment: Not sure why did you put A1 into A, and not into B

Answer (score 3):

It's the `#A1 margin-left` what causes the trouble.

`#A` has a width of `200px`, and `#A1.margin-left` was set to 200px.

Comment: @blasteralfred in that case, wouldn't it be better to move `A1` outside of `A` between `A` and `B`?

Comment: no.. still i can't shift layout.. its fixed.. `:(` .. I want the exact layout

Answer (score 0):

First, you somehow forgot the style for A1 in your fiddle :)
Second, the parent container, A, is 200px wide, so your A1 starts just outside its right border.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the margin-left. If you reduce it to 10 px you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin-left: 200px; from your style for A1

```
#A1 {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```